# VSCode: Cannot 'import matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use python on VSCode for the first time. I am working on Mac. 
I have a file plot.py:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)  # Create a list of evenly-spaced numbers over the range
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))       # Plot the sine of each x point
plt.show()
```

When I am in the directory with plot.py and, from terminal, run:

`$python plot.py` I get no error and a graph with the desired sine wave opens.

If I run `$python3 plot.py` I also receive no error.

In VSCode I have the following interpreter options:

[image]

Regardless of which one I use I get the following error:

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/ealejo/Documents/PROGRAMS/Visual_CS/Python/plot.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ealejo/Documents/PROGRAMS/Visual_CS/Python/plot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.051 seconds
```

I have tried `$pip uninstall matplotlib` and then  `$pip install matplotlib`
I have done the same with pip3.

I have done `$conda install matplotlib`

I have removed matplotlib with `rm -rf makefile``

Nothing seems to fix the problem.

Comment: in your terminal, see what's the output for `which python`. Make sure you use the same python in your VSCode interpreter. If it's not listed in VSCode interpreters, you need to add it

Comment: Double-check your workspace's  `pythonPath`

Comment: my settings.json file has pythonPath set to  `"/usr/local/bin/python3"`. I get the same result when I do `which python3` in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Turns out PlatformIO and Python 3 are not compatible. Uninstalling platformio solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As in comment by @Hy L:
In VS Code,

1. press `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open command palette
2. Type 'interpreter'
3. Make sure to choose the correct python interpreter (with the right environment).

This should fix the issue. If not, make sure it is installed in this environment (`pip install matplotlib`).

Answer (score 0):

If your pip can't find a suitible matplot version you can use apt to install it if it has been provided by you distribution support:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

For mac it may be:

```
Brew install python3-matplotlib
```

Other option would be:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sure, i'll do as you say.

Comment: It helps, your answer is currently in the low quality answers queue so improving it will help avoid having it voted to be deleted

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the command palette in VSCode by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P.
2. In the command palette, type 'interpreter' and select the option "Python: Select Interpreter."
3. Choose a Python Interpreter from the list. For example, you can select "Python 3.7.3 - 64 bit."
4. After selecting the Python interpreter, open the integrated terminal in VSCode or use Jupyter Notebook.
5. In the terminal or notebook, run the following command to install Matplotlib using pip:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Remember that when you want to use the Matplotlib library in your code, make sure you have selected the interpreter where you previously ran the command pip install matplotlib.